# Why the lines are crossed out and the error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Why the lines are crossed out and the error where the dot is I don't understand

```
package com.ggenius.whattowearkotlin.data.network

import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import com.ggenius.whattowearkotlin.internal.NoConnectivityException
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response

class ConnectivityInterceptorImpl(
    context: Context?
) : ConnectivityInterceptor {

    private val appContext = context.applicationContext

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (!isOnline())
            throw NoConnectivityException()
        return chain.proceed(chain.request())
    }

    private fun isOnline() : Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = appContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
        as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
    }
}
```

Check screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuelU.png)

Comment: Read this. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: Hover the mouse over things and it'll tell ya

Answer (score 1):

This line is crossed out

```
val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
```

Because the `getActiveNetworkInfo()` method is deprecated according to their API

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetworkInfo()

Answer (score 1):

## Why the lines are crossed out?

The lines are crossed out because they are [Deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html). In Android Studio by default the deprecated use of functions, classes, variables etc. are styled as strikeout. You want to know why? It's because by default settings it's set as so. Here is Screenshot [image]

## Why the error where the dot is I don't understand?

The `context.applicationContext` is showing error because your `context` is nullable. Whenever you define your variable with `Type` followed by `?` is nullable in `Kotlin`.

As you passing `context: Context?`, so context is nullable. To access nullable objects properties or methods you need to use `objectName` followed by `?`. This prevents the `NullPointerException` that makes Kotlin null safe.

In you example you need to do;

```
private val appContext = context?.applicationContext 
// Note that appContext will also be nullable.
```

[Further Reading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html)